# Streamlining R code, double for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, bigdata

I have a rather large dataset that I've read into R and formatted the way I would like.  I have 3 columns, latitude, longitude, and an indicator for whether or not there is snow at that location.

I also have another (larger) dataset with 3 columns: latitude, longitude, and elevation.  I would like to sort through these latitudes and longitudes and match them up with the lats and longs in my other dataset to add in the elevation.  Essentially I would like 1 dataset with 4 columns: lat, long, indicator, and elevation.

I have written a program which does this, but for these very large datasets, it is not efficient enough to let it run.  I do not want to kill my personal PC.  Is there any way to speed up my code?

Thanks so much.

```
      ## Looping through
      for(i in 1:len){
        for(j in 1:78355){
          if(OrigDat1[i,2] == Elev04[j,2] && OrigDat1[i,1] == Elev04[j,1]){
            Elev.vec[i] = as.numeric(Elev04[j,3])
          }
        }
      }
```

In the above code the 'len' term varies depending on the size of the shapefile I strip the data down to.  It has a length anywhere from 1000 - 50000 locations.

I can provide you with more information if needed.

Thanks again.

Comment: have you looked at the `merge` function? `help("merge").`

Comment: No - I will take a look at the application of that tonight - thanks!

Comment: To start try `merge(OrigDat1, Elev04, by=1:2)`

Comment: Thanks to all! I think that this worked (it just resorted the row order - I will verify this is the case).